# UITableView cell constraints problem - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I started to get this constraints error:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000014419a0 V:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x7f809779fae0]   (active, names: '|':mChat.ChatCell:0x7f8097534600'ChatCell' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001441b30 UIImageView:0x7f809779fae0.bottom == mChat.ChatCell:0x7f8097534600'ChatCell'.bottom - 20   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001440eb0 UIImageView:0x7f809779fae0.height == 150   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001440550 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' mChat.ChatCell:0x7f8097534600'ChatCell'.height == 60.5   (active)>"
```

The problem appears when the UITableView has at least two images in it, then I get these constraints errors. Or when I add another image to the UITableView.
Here are my constraints:

```
func setupMediaMessage(){

        mediaMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mediaMessage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        mediaMessage.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        mediaMessage.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        mediaMessage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let constraints = [
            mediaMessage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),
            mediaMessage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
            mediaMessage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            mediaMessage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        ]
        outcomingConstraint = mediaMessage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 24)
        incomingConstraint = mediaMessage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -24)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```

Don't worry about the trailing and leading constraints, I'm just checking if those images are incoming or outcoming.
My Github repo: https://github.com/realpaliy/mChat/blob/master/mChat/Controllers/Chats/ChatCell.swift. So, the UITableView looks good, but why do I get those errors?
[image: SH]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the layout looks correct, the conflicts are likely due to the internal auto-layout engine, and the order in which the constraints are evaluated.

Try this -- it *should* get rid of the warnings, without changing the end result:

```
    let bAnchor = mediaMessage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
    bAnchor.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
    let constraints = [
        mediaMessage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),

        //mediaMessage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        bAnchor,

        mediaMessage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
        mediaMessage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
    ]
```

**EDIT**

Note: I do not work for Apple - these are simply my observations:

When a cell is instantiated and / or dequeued, auto-layout uses the current row height to lay out the cell contents. It then uses the constraints on the cell contents to determine the actual row height. This can cause conflict warnings if the row is not tall enough for the generated height. By changing the Priority on the bottom-most constraint - or, I believe, on explicit element height constraints - to 999, that allows auto-layout to first *break* the constraint and then re-enforce it... *without* generating debug warnings.

You should (may?) also be able to eliminate the warnings by setting a big enough value for `tableView.estimatedRowHeight`.

Comment: Thank you!!!. But can you explain what it actually means? What is the priority and what it does to the constraints?

Comment: @JohnSnow - I edited my answer with some further explanation (that is, to the best of my knowledge).